# How can I add a link to the very top bar (black bar) in SharePoint 2016 on-Prem

Tags: top-link-bar

I need to add a link to the very top (black bar) on SharePoint 2016 instead of the Suitebar. I'd hate to edit the Masterpage.  Has anyone ever done this?

Bismarck

Comment: Are you looking to do it across the site collection, or just a few pages?

Comment: I am looking to do across the whole farm so its on every page. I don't have enough room on the Suitebar to keep it responsive so I'm looking at the black bar above it.

Comment: I’d look at adding a js link to the masterpage to dynamically add links or other content across the farm and then you can just update that JS file when you need to update rather than the masterpage itself

Comment: Thanks, I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

What about this powershell?

```
    $wa = Get-SPWebApplication "https://pippo.pluto.it"
    $wa.SuiteNavBrandingLogoNavigationUrl = "/"
    $wa.SuiteNavBrandingLogoTitle = "Torna all'home page"
    $wa.SuiteNavBrandingLogoUrl = "/SiteAssets/Logo.png" 
    $wa.Update()
```

[image]

Comment: Maurizio, I think this just puts it in the Suite Bar, not the Bar above it.  Am I wrong?

Comment: Isn't it the black bar? see the image i've added

Comment: Yes, that appears to work, I just need to move it to the right side instead of in the middle.

Comment: I don't think is possible only with powershell

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure if this works for SharePoint 2016, but it does work for SharePoint 2013, and affects the Web Application:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -erroraction SilentlyContinue
$webApp = Get-SPWebApplication https://SHAREPOINT
$HTML = @'
 <script>
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event){
 var ul = document.getElementsByClassName("ms-core-suiteLinkList"); 
 var li = document.createElement("li");
 li.innerHTML = '<a class="ms-core-suiteLink-a" id="ctl00_ctl45_ShellHome" href="https://SHAREPOINT/Pages/default.aspx"><span>Home</span></a>';
 li.setAttribute('class','ms-core-suiteLink');
 ul[0].insertBefore(li, ul[0].childNodes[0]);
 });
 </script>
 <div class='ms-core-brandingText'>SharePoint</div>
'@

$webApp.SuiteBarBrandingElementHtml = $HTML
$webApp.Update()
$webApp = Get-SPWebApplication https://SHAREPOINT
$webApp.SuiteBarBrandingElementHtml = $HTML
$webApp.Update()
```